# How to assign values to array in CPLEX with C++?

Tags: optimization, cplex, modeling-languages

I am new to CPLEX. I am using CPLEX with Xcode in macOS.

I have three arrays (known parameters used in optimisation) which I define as

```
  IloNumArray capacity(env), fixedCost(env);
  FloatMatrix cost(env);
```

I then assign values to this arrays as

```
   fixedCost=[480, 200, 320, 340, 300];
   cost=[[ 24, 74, 31, 51, 84],
    [ 57, 54, 86, 61, 68],
    [ 57, 67, 29, 91, 71],
    [ 54, 54, 65, 82, 94],
    [ 98, 81, 16, 61, 27],
    [ 13, 92, 34, 94, 87],
    [ 54, 72, 41, 12, 78],
    [ 54, 64, 65, 89, 89]];
   capacity=[ 3, 1, 2, 4, 1];
```

But, I am getting the following error:

```
    Expected variable name or 'this' in lambda capture list
```

How can I get rid of this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the docs, `IloNumArray`s constructor signature is

```cpp
public IloNumArray(const IloEnv env, IloInt n, IloNum f0, IloNum f1, ...)
```

which creates an array of n floating point objects for use in a model. Note
that the constructor is a C-Style variadic function due to the `...` parameter.
Thus, you can assign your values while calling the constructor, i.e.

```cpp
IloNumArray capacity(env, 5, 3, 1, 2, 4, 1);
IloNumArray fixedCost(env, 5, 480, 200, 320, 340, 300);
```

For the second one it's not clear what `FloatMatrix` should be.
I assume you use the (C++11) alias

```cpp
using FloatMatrix = IloArray<IloNumArray>; 
// C++98: typedef IloArray<IloNumArray> FloatMatrix;
```

Then you could do it like this

```cpp
FloatMatrix cost(env);

cost.add(IloNumArray(env, 5, 24, 74, 31, 51, 84));
cost.add(IloNumArray(env, 5, 57, 54, 86, 61, 68));
cost.add(IloNumArray(env, 5, 54, 54, 65, 82, 94));
cost.add(IloNumArray(env, 5, 98, 81, 16, 61, 27));
cost.add(IloNumArray(env, 5, 13, 92, 34, 94, 87));
cost.add(IloNumArray(env, 5, 54, 72, 41, 12, 78));
cost.add(IloNumArray(env, 5, 54, 64, 65, 89, 89));
```

To access the arrays, you simply call `capacity[i]` and `cost[i][j]`.